# How can I transform � into ö in my bootstrap datatable?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, utf-8, datatables

I have the problem that in my datatable `ä`,`ö`,`ü` etc. is displayed as �.

The strange thing is: Everywhere else on my website the "umlauts" are displayed correct. As you see I am using a german language attribute, and `Einträge` is displayed right. So the problem occurs only inside my table.

The other thing: On my localhost, everything is displayed fine, also the table. It happens only on my server. Here an example how I see it on my website:

```js
$('.data-table').DataTable({
    "language": {
            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/German.json",
        },
  "scrollX": true,
  
});
```

```css
div.dataTables_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css">

<script src="https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="data-table table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>     
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Sm�rebr�d</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>Mal�r</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>Mal�r</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
   
  
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @madalinivascu Yes I have that already. My editor (TextWrangler) has the encoding `Unicode UTF-8` and also in my header I am using `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try adding following 2 lines right after selecting the database if you are fetching data from database? I hope that can solve your issue.

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
```

Comment: I tested it in my code like this `$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";port=8889;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
 $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");` Unfortunately no change

Comment: I wrote it like this: `$db -> exec("set names utf8");` and working!!

Comment: Congratulations! Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Html entity for unique symbol or character, see [`example`](https://jsfiddle.net/yck3tvgp/1/). 
Reference  http://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html

Comment: Do you mean I need to write everytime for example: &Ouml;?